# Overriding Ordering[Int] in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to sort an array of integers with a custom ordering.

E.g.

```
quickSort[Int](indices)(Ordering.by[Int, Double](value(_)))
```

Basically, I'm trying to sort indices of rows by the values of a particular column. I end up with a stackoverflow error when I run this on a fairly large data. If I use a more direct approach (e.g. sorting Tuple), this is not a problem.

Is there a problem if you try to extend the default Ordering[Int]?

You can reproduce this like this:

```
val indices = (0 to 99999).toArray
val values = Array.fill[Double](100000)(math.random)
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort[Int](indices)(Ordering.by[Int, Double](values(_))) // Works
val values2 = Array.fill[Double](100000)(0.0)
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort[Int](indices)(Ordering.by[Int, Double](values2(_))) // Fails
```

**Update:**

I think that I found out what the problem is (am answering my own question). It seems that I've created a paradoxical situation by changing the ordering definition of integers.

Within the quickSort algorithm itself, array positions are also integers, and there are certain statements comparing positions of arrays. This position comparison should be following the standard integer ordering.

But because of the new definition, now these position comparators are also following the indexed value comparator and things are getting really messed up.

I suppose that at least for the time being, I shouldn't be changing these default value type ordering as library might depend on default value type ordering.

**Update2**

It turns out that the above is in fact not the problem and there's a bug in quickSort when used together with Ordering. When a new Ordering is defined, the equality operator among Ordering is 'equiv', however the quickSort uses '=='. This results in the indices being compared, rather than indexed values being compared.

Comment: Are you using the standard ``scala.util.Sorting`` object for sorting or is this your own implementation? And what is the type of the ``indices`` value?

Comment: Hi, "indices" is an Array[Int]. "value" is an Array[Double].

Comment: How large is "fairly large"?

Comment: 100,000 elements. I just found out that this happens when value is a degenerate case like all zeroes - otherwise, if value is reasonably spread out with different values, it works without problems. 
    quickSort[Double](value) would work just fine in any case.